# Add counter to social medias like twitter and google plus

Tags: javascript, twitter, google-plus, social-media

I'm not too familiar with the API of Twitter and Google Plus. Can someone put some light in my problem? I want to add a counter to my Twitter, Google Plus and Stumble Upon button. This will be integrated in my wordpress post and pages. I think already implemented the facebook button. My only remaining problem are, Twitter, Google Plus and Stumble Upon (optional).

Thank You!

```
<!-- 
Facebook
/////////////////
--> 
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&t=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>"  name="fb_share" type="box_count" target="_blank" id="facebook">
    Share
</a>


<!-- 
Twitter
/////////////////
--> 

<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>&text=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>" class="twitter-share-button" id='twitter' target="_blank">
    Tweet
</a>


<!-- 
Google Plus
/////////////////
--> 

<a href="https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()) . " " . urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>" id='gplus' target="_blank">
    Google Plus
</a>


<!-- 
Stumble Upon
/////////////////
--> 

<a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>" target="_blank" id='stumble'>
    Stumble
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter share count: https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons

Google+ +1 count: http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_floating_style addthis_counter_style"    style="left:50px;top:160px;">
 <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="box_count"></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_tweet" tw:count="vertical"></a>
 <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="tall"></a>
 <a class="addthis_counter"></a>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true}; </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5178354276acf324"></script>
```

Comment: It may work, but could you add a little explanation to your code block, too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the counters...

I have a gist that does that for Facebook Pinterest and Twitter https://gist.github.com/andrefrd/9520512